# Cross filter trouble | unable to select a parent where there are no grandchildren of a certain type

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, cross-filter

I have a challenge: I want to be able to find the parent objects that do NOT have records of grandchildren of a certain type.

To illustrate the challenge: I have the following objects in Salesforce: **Parent_*c***, **Child_c**, **Grandchild_*c***  where there is a one-to-many relationship between **Parent_c** and **Child_*c*** and again a one-to-many for **Child_c** to **GrandChild__c**.

Now take it that I have two parent records that have a **MainName_*c*** field that stores their names (John and Jane), also take it that I have two **Child_c** records both having a **MainName_*c*** field that stores their names (Michael and Pat) and also another field called **Parent_c** and the value in both record is John.

Now imagine that I have two more records, these belong to the **Grandchild_*c*** object. These records also have the **MainName_c** field (with Debby and Jim) and a **Parent__c** field (Michael). I know that if I ask the question of "list me all parents that do not have a grandchild called Debby" my answer will be to list only the record with Pat, as it is the only record that does not have a grandchild called Debby, but is it possible to ask this question using cross filters in a report in Salesforce and how would I do it if it is?

Comment: Uuuh.. why Pat? It's been a long day over here but I'd say `Grandchild != Debby` is met by Jane (top level), not Pat (middle level). Image plz?

Comment: Also - screw cross filters? Have you tried making a custom report type "Parents - with or without - Children - with or without - Grandchildren" and then plain old filters? If you did - what didn't work as expected?

Comment: ...very long day here! yes Pat is mid level, it should be Jane. I will try using the custom report type and use the with or without join...